# How to create a AngularJs provider with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I've created a Directive and inside I use some Css classes and it would be nice if you can config the Css classes on Application start in the config section. I thougt a provider would be the right solution. But I have no clue how to create a provider with TypeScript Classdefinition and how to initialize it.

I've searched the web but found no working solution so far.

Comment: Typescript is a superset of Javascript, so if in doubt, just write Javascript as you find it in AngujarJS' documentation about providers…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little rough but should give you a general idea on how to do it. Providers in general are kind of pain.

```
class CommonServiceProvider implements ng.IServiceProvider {
    config = {
        path:"/test"
    };
    $get = () => {
        return {
            config: this.config
        };
    };
}

angular.module("app).provider("commonConfig", () =>
    new CommonServiceProvider()
);
```